# LaTeX not working on matplotlib text

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I've been having this trouble for a long time whenever I want to render LaTeX for plot labelling and text, it works sometimes for some symbols but not others. For example in my script shown here generates the plot below:

```
from matplotlib import rc
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.plot(a_t,asol[:,0],label ='$\psi$')
plt.plot(a_t,rho,label ="$\rho/\rho_c$")
plt.xlabel(r"$\xi$",fontsize=15)
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D
plt.legend(loc='upper left',prop={'size':12},numpoints=1)
```

[image: plt_result]

I've tried other symbols, $\pi$ works okay but $\theta$ only shows "heta" without the t. I'm confused by why some symbols works for LaTeX and some don't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that certain characters in Python strings have special meanings, e.g. `\r` for carriage return, `\t` for tab. That's why you're only getting the strange results some of the time, since `\p` doesn't have a special meaning. So either make sure your backslashes are treated as literal backslashes by escaping them:

```
plt.plot(a_t,rho,label = "$\\rho/\\rho_c$")
```

Or use raw strings:

```
plt.plot(a_t,rho,label = r"$\rho/\rho_c$")
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for letting me know!